# Report Linux memory cache content

Tags: linux, memory, cache

Is there a way to report the contents of the file cache held on RAM?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the 'top' command?  It has tons of metrics.

Comment: As far as I know the file cache is across the entire system and doesnt relate to indivdual processes. Also I want to know which files are being cached, so not something top would do.